# activerecord/pg: support automatic timestamps in DDL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, timestamp

**Updated (to show code)**

I'd like to mimic ActiveRecord's [automatic timestamps](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Timestamp.html) directly in the database, but *without explicitly adding this logic after every migration's `create_table()` call*.

Here's what I do now:

```
class StatusQuo < My::Migration::Subclass
  def self.up
    create_table :tbl do |t|
      ... some columns ...
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_default_now(:tbl, :created_at)  # ALTER COLUMN ... DEFAULT NOW()
    add_default_now(:tbl, :updated_at)  # ALTER COLUMN ... DEFAULT NOW()
    add_updated_at_trigger(:tbl)        # BEFORE UPDATE ON ... trg_updated_at()
  end
end
```

By contrast, here's what I'd like to do:

```
class Druthers < My::Migration::Subclass
  def self.up
    create_table :tbl do |t|
      ... some columns ...
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Is there an easy or recommended way to accomplish this?  Using activerecord 3, postgresql 8.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the best I could come up with so far, full source [here](http://pastebin.com/YGdfwrZS):

In `config/environment.rb` check to see if our connection adapter is PostgreSQL.  If so, `require` a file that does the following:

1. Wrap `ColumnDefinition#to_sql` to force defaults

   Force "created_at" and "updated_at" to have DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
2. Wrap `create_table` to conditionally apply the trigger

   If the newly created table has an "updated_at" column, install a trigger referencing a database FUNCTION assumed to exist.

Not pretty (need to have maintain a FUNCTION definition outside of this code) and not complete (`change_table` won't handle introducing timestamps properly), but good enough.